# jquery - http post request returning xml instead of json in android browser

Tags: android, jquery, json

I see an issue only in older android browsers when I try making an http POST request using jQuery. The response I get is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.12 02/15/2012 05:30 PM"/>
    <grammars>
      <include href="http://myURL">
        <doc xml:lang="en" title="Generated"/> 
      </include>
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://myURL2">
      <resource path="register"/> 
    </resources>
  </application> 
{"myID":"abcd"}
```

This has an xml header of some sort prepended to the json content in the end.

On other browsers (even the android 4.0 OS) I get the expected content which is -

```
{"myID":"abcd"}
```

I make the request as follows -

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    contentType: contentType,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: postData,
    success: function(data){
        $.isFunction(successCb) && successCb(data); 
    },  
    error: function(data1){  
        $.isFunction(failureCb) && failureCb(data1);  
    }  
});
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: perhaps something to do with those browsers default accept headers

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RF23z/1/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RF23z/1/show/

tested this on my android 2.2 , and 4.0.4 , works fine for me.

can you make sure the response from server sends a header for json?

Comment: I can see the correct json on all other browsers. This is an issue only on the older android ones.

Comment: What versions? as I wrote, I just tested through 2.2 .

can you make sure headers are coming from server are application/json?

Comment: what is the URL of your json request.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot reveal it. Bound by confidentiality agreement :)

Comment: its okay! I think all that you are missing is SERVER's header! Because in my case the youtube feed in json, returns proper header and its working fine in lower version of android for me.

Comment: what do you mean by that? how would I need to fix it? Its working fine in all other browsers except some older android ones.

Comment: There are headers in response to every request. That tells the browser, what kind of file is this, and few other details.

your request should return application/json as header.

which server side language you are using?

Comment: run my example in your anroid browser, at http://fiddle.jshell.net/RF23z/1/show/ , if you can see some feeds in console, that means browser is okay with application/json request. There is some problem in your server side code. Request you to share